# Placemark that pulls information off an excel sheet row and display's the data in the description part of the Placemark

Tags: google-earth, xml, excel, csv, kmz

I am trying to find out if a certain function is available to link an excel sheet with a kmz.

What i need to happen is have a Placemark that pulls information off an excel sheet row and display's the data in the description part of the Placemark.

I know that there is a macro in excel to export KMZ file but I want the KMZ itself to perform the task of collecting the information and displaying it.

I would guess that it would be an extension of the “ad link command,” but I can’t seem to get my head around it. This would be cut down on data duplication if there was a way of doing it.

If you know of a way to do this please comment.

Thanks

Shane